# How to display image using CreateDIBSection

Tags: c++

I want to display a images on window, am giving image data as in buffer `&CaptureBuffer` to `CreateDIBSection`, CreateDIBForVideo method is calling from thread on main().
 dont know where im going wrong it is showing black window.

```
    void CreateDIBForVideo()
{
    // ScreenCaptureProcessorGDI is a class it have initialization for capture window screen  
    screenObject = new ScreenCaptureProcessorGDI();
    screenObject->init();

    HDC DisplayDC = CreateDC((LPCWSTR)"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    BITMAPINFO bmpInfo = { 0 };
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize= sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = screenObject->lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Width;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight= screenObject->lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Height;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = (4 * screenObject->lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Width * screenObject->lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Height);
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    CaptureBuffer = NULL;
    HDC pXorDC = CreateCompatibleDC(DisplayDC);
    HBITMAP hXorDib = CreateDIBSection(DisplayDC, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&CaptureBuffer, NULL, 0);

    hXorTemp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(pXorDC, hXorDib);
    // startGrab this thread capture a windows screen after init() 
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&startGrab, NULL, 0, NULL);
}


void startGrab()
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++)
    {
       // grabImage will capture window screen and send image as a buffer to `CaptureBuffer` 
        screenObject->grabImage();      
        PaintViewerWindow();
        UpdateWindow(global_hWnd);
        ::Sleep(2000);
    }
}

void PaintViewerWindow()
{
    HDC paintDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    paintDC = BeginPaint(global_hWnd, &ps);
    SetStretchBltMode(paintDC, HALFTONE);       
    BitBlt(paintDC, 0, 0, 1366, 768, pXorDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);        
    EndPaint(global_hWnd, &ps);

}
```

Comment: That (LPCWSTR) cast is a nasty mistake.  No error checking either, so it just spirals into a black hole from there.

Comment: @HansPassant Nop! its a typecasting .. but anyhow thank you for the reply, I posted my solution below.

Comment: It's incorrect casting. If you want a wide string make one. `L"Wide String"` Just because you can blindly cast something doesn't magically make it right.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution for the above problem
It because of `UCHAR *CaptureBuffer` am directly passing `CaptureBuffer` to the `CreateDIBSection` now i changed to copying `UCHAR *CaptureBuffer` to `char *DisplayBuffer` its working fine now.

```
     UCHAR *CaptureBuffer = NULL;
        char *DisplayBuffer = NULL;
        long CaptureSize = NULL;

        void saveImage(unsigned int frame_num, BITMAPINFO &lBmpInfo, std::unique_ptr<BYTE> pBuf, UCHAR* &CaptureBuffer, long &CaptureSize)
            {

                    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHeader;

                    bmpFileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
                    bmpFileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
                    bmpFileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
                    bmpFileHeader.bfType = 'MB';
                    bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

                    CaptureSize = lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
                    CaptureBuffer = (UCHAR*)malloc(CaptureSize);

                    memcpy(CaptureBuffer, pBuf.get(), lBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);          
                    //Here am copying CaptureBuffer(uchar) to DisplayBuffer(char)
                    memcpy(DisplayBuffer, CaptureBuffer, CaptureSize);
                    lresult = 0;

            }

    void CreateDIBForVideo()
{
    // ScreenCaptureProcessorGDI is a class it have initialization for capture window screen  
    screenObject = new ScreenCaptureProcessorGDI();
    screenObject->init();

    HDC DisplayDC = CreateDC((LPCWSTR)"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    BITMAPINFO bmpInfo = { 0 };
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize= sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = screenObject->lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Width;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight= screenObject->lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Height;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = (4 * screenObject->lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Width * screenObject->lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Height);
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    CaptureBuffer = NULL;
    HDC pXorDC = CreateCompatibleDC(DisplayDC);
    HBITMAP hXorDib = CreateDIBSection(DisplayDC, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&DisplayBuffer, NULL, 0);

    hXorTemp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(pXorDC, hXorDib);
    // startGrab this thread capture a windows screen after init() 
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&startGrab, NULL, 0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: @RetiredNinja apologize for it .. am new to c++ I stuck in some place of code so posted here but no one replied for it and i find solution from myself and posted ... you negative voted for my post think about it ....